# Pyomo: ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:list index out of range

Tags: python, modeling, pyomo

So I am working on a model in Pyomo using Pycharm. When I run the model in Pycharm (to test if the syntax is fine, etc.) i don´t get any mistakes however if I run it by cmd using "pyomo solve --solver=glpk --stream-solver --summary model.py" I get the following output

```
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
[    0.47] Creating model
[    0.47] Applying solver
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.57
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 --write C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmpppxfx743.glpk.raw --wglp
 C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmpsykfeh2b.glpk.glp --cpxlp C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmp9ogdtp4l.pyomo.lp
Reading problem data from 'C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmp9ogdtp4l.pyomo.lp'...
C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmp9ogdtp4l.pyomo.lp:42834: warning: lower bound of variable 'x2017' redefined
C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmp9ogdtp4l.pyomo.lp:42834: warning: upper bound of variable 'x2017' redefined
7105 rows, 2953 columns, 18462 non-zeros
936 integer variables, all of which are binary
43770 lines were read
Writing problem data to 'C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmpsykfeh2b.glpk.glp'...
36501 lines were written
GLPK Integer Optimizer, v4.57
7105 rows, 2953 columns, 18462 non-zeros
936 integer variables, all of which are binary
Preprocessing...
LP RELAXATION HAS NO DUAL FEASIBLE SOLUTION
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 4.3 Mb (4478268 bytes)
Writing MIP solution to 'C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\untitled\tmpppxfx743.glpk.raw'...
10060 lines were written

[    0.93] Processing results
    Number of solutions: 0
    Solver results file: results.yml

==========================================================
Solution Summary
==========================================================
[    0.93] Pyomo Finished

**ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
        list index out of range**
```

Does anybody know what could be the case? I am not sure if it might just be unfeasible (how it is said in the output), becuase the Error-message does not fit to this kind of problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the LP dual is infeasible, then it's possible that your original model may be unbounded. To troubleshoot the exception, it may be helpful running the solve as a python script. That is, add `SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model, tee=True)` and `model.display()` to the bottom of your model file and executing it as a script: `python model.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it the way you described it. This way I don´t get the Error-message of "list index out of range", but it is still infeasible. Also I noticed that all values of all variables are the same as they were initialized. So I guess there has to be a constraint that can't be fullfilled.